# I'm having trouble with the backwards direction, and I need some insight on how to do this while using a contradiction.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following set identity: $(N\cap M)\cup (D\cap M) = M\cap (N\cup D)$.

Rewrite this identity as a biconditional statement involving set membership.

Prove this biconditional statement.

First, consider the forward direction.
Assume: $x\in (N\cap M)\cup (D\cap M)$

Since $(x\in N \cap M) \lor (x\in D\cap M)$, you can deduce $x\in M$ either way.

Then $x\in N\cap M \implies x\in N$.

Similarly, $x\in D\cap M \implies x\in D$.

Thus either $x\in N\cup D$.

Therefore, $x\in M\cap (N\cup D)$.

Finally, consider the backward direction.

Assume $x\in M\cap(N\cup D)$.

Aiming for a contradiction, suppose $x\not\in (N\cap M) \cup(D\cap M)$.

From $x\not\in(N\cap M) \cup (D\cap M)$, we see $x\not\in (N\cap M)$ or $x\not\in (D\cap M)$.

By using Demorgan's Law, $x\in N\cup M$ and $x\in D\cup M$.

If $x\not\in N\cup D$, then $x\in M$.

From the first assumption, $x\in M$ and $x\in N$ or $x\in D$.

If $x\in N$ we see $x\in M \cap N$.

The same thing can also be said if $x\in D$, $x\in M \cap D$.

Since $x\in M$ and $x\not\in (N\cap M)\cup(D\cap M)$, we see $x\in (N\cup D)$.

Thus we've found a contradiction: both $x\in N\cup D$ and

$x\not\in N\cup D$

So the contradiction is false: $x\in M\cap(N\cup D)$.

Ergo, $x\in (N\cap M) \cup (D\cap M)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally don't need to use contradiction for such "basic" inclusions.

In the $\supseteq$ direction you also can chose $x\in M\cap (N\cup D)$. This means $x\in M$ and $x\in N\cup D$. So we have $x\in M$ and $x\in N$ which means $x\in M\cap N$ or $x\in M$ and $x\in D$ which similarly means $x\in M\cap D$. Hence $x\in (M\cap N)\cup (M\cap D)$.

Does this clarifies your question?

Comment: I've done the same thing (I forgot to add), but I need to prove the problem in a different way as well. So that's why I was trying to do a contradiction to prove for the second. The contradiction that I've been trying to prove is incorrect. And if there's another efficient way of doing it that would be helpful.

Comment: @BrandonNguyen sorry I don't see why to prove basic set theory stuff with contradiction or other methods. I mean you can show that if $x$ is not in the RHS then $x$ is not contained in the LHS but this is basically the same proof using negation.